# Unable to reset password in Recovery Mode

Tags: macos, recovery

Unfortunately, I am unable to log in to my Mac Mini OS X (10.8.5). I am trying to recover the password with **Recovery Mode** by pressing `CMD + R`.

I executed the `resetpassword` command, but the window that appears doesn't list my volume and I can't select my user account.

[recovery mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl9qM.jpg)
[image: Resetpassword window]

Comment: Hi. I commented on your [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920686/unable-to-reset-password-in-recovery-mode-of-mac). Could you update your question here with more details — how exactly did you get locked out & do you have FileVault enabled? If you followed the instructions from the [osxdaily article](http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/25/change-admin-password-mac/) exactly & get an error at `ls /Users`, that suggests some kind of data loss or corruption.

Comment: Yes filevault is enabled, that is the reason why i am unable to reset password in single user mode.

Comment: When you turn on FileVault, you're presented with a [recovery key](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837). If you didn't write it down anywhere or [save it with Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH11382?locale=en_US), you won't be able to decrypt your disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I called apple support team for further help. They took required information from me and helped to reinstall OS. My data is erased as previously i did not kept any backup and after reinstallation it was like new MAC machine.

Comment: WHAT APPLE TOLD TO YOU ? I HAVE THE SAME PROBLEM THANKS