# Reset Password app in recovery mode not showing and disks

Tags: macos, keychain, recovery

*Note: this question is a duplicate of [Unable to reset password in Recovery Mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199568/unable-to-reset-password-in-recovery-mode), but the solution mentioned there was to reinstall the OS, which is not really the solution I'm striving for if there is any other way to solve this.*

Due to a problem with my keychain mentioned here [OS X is repeatedly asking for login keychain password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231340/os-x-is-repeatedly-asking-for-login-keychain-password), I now wanted to **reset my user folder permissions** by booting in recovery mode and then via the `resetpassword` app.

But **none of my disks shows up here**:

[image]

(My Mac, which I got with Mountain Lion, is meanwhile on El Capitan. I have only one user, which is also the admin user. Beside the keychain issue I linked above, I haven't noticed any other issues with my system / users so far.)

Comment: Did you enable FileVault previously?

Comment: @klanomath Yes, it was enabled before, I turned if off just few minutes ago and it's still decrypting.

Comment: You have to wait until decryption has finished (which may take several hours depending on the size and kind {HDD|SSD} of your internal disk)!

Comment: @klanomath After disabling FileVault, the HD shows up again. (Weird, why would the Reset Password app not ask me for the decryption password and decrypt it there on the fly, instead of having to boot in regular mode again and deactivate it. Not very logical to me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **disabling FileVault** under `System Settings > Security & Privacy`, it's working fine again.

Comment: Is this a Mac bug or?